# Github does not preview files pushed to remote repository

Tags: git, github

Whenever I commit and push files to my remote repository, I am unable to view the file and I see the following screen:

[image: just raw URL access]

But when other collaborators push to the same repository, the files can be previewed. Can someone please point out what might be the issue? The document size which does not preview is 102 KB.

Comment: Could you show and example of the other files? Github does not support previewing every format. My best guess is Github can't preview a DOCX file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Github does not support .doc files.they can be downloaded from the commit. But can not be viewed. I tried the same file as PDF format and it worked fine.